# GRUB problem in 13.04

Tags: grub2

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 in Lenovo G580 laptop. After installed successfully restarted my laptop. "grub not found" message appeared when ever pressed power button. I reinstalled again and installed "grub" by using ""so I realized something problem than removed <kbd>F12</kbd> function key. Now also same error message appearing whenever I pressed power button. Finally I deleted 12.04 version then installed 13.04. Even now also same error message appearing.

Now I am realizing the grub which I installed is making some problem. How can I remove this grub?

My system windows 7 OS also.
previously both were working good. 
help me

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. I expect you have your Live CD/USB with you. Just follow the simple steps and you'll solve it in less than 5 minutes.
[How to Repair, Restore, or Reinstall Grub 2 with a Ubuntu Live CD or USB](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd#.UqMEhrVdVCE)
Note: Remember to replace the blue parts with the relevant partitions.

Comment: first, from your liveCD run Gparted.. the corrrect command would be sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
Just see in gparted which is the suitable one for you. I had sdb3 for me. Replace XY with the necessary drive characters and you can proceed then. All the best.